# f2py wrapper automatically assign values to optional arguments in subroutine

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm using f2py to wrap a module.f90 so that I can use it from python. The problem is that in the module there is a subroutine that contains many input(in) optional variables and when I call the subroutine from a python script it seems like the optional variables are set to some random value.

This is what the subrotuine looks like.

```
module checkpt
    implicit none

    contains
    subroutine checkpoint(cpt, debug, mode, file_name)
        implicit none
    
        integer, intent(in) :: cpt
        logical, intent(in) :: debug
        character(len=*), optional :: mode
        character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: file_name
        character(len=30) :: def_name = 'checkpoint.dat'

        if(present(file_name)) def_name = file_name
        -- some code...

        ! check if a mode is selected and print the correct stuff
        if(present(mode)) then
            if(mode .eq. 'TIME') then
                -- do some stuff...
            else if(mode .eq. 'VALUES') then
                -- do other stuff...              
            else 
                stop "ERROR - Wrong checkpoint mode: must be one among 'VALUES','TIME'."
            end if
        end if
        
    end subroutine checkpoint       
end module checkpt
```

and the python version

```
from fmatmult import f_mat_mult as fmm
from fcheckpt import checkpt as cpt

debug = True

sizes = [50,100,200,400,800]#,1600,3200,6400]

for i in range(len(sizes)):
    fmm.mat_mult1(sizes[i])
    cpt.checkpoint(cpt=1,debug=debug)
```

but what I get is the following:
STOP ERROR - Wrong checkpoint mode: must be one among 'VALUES','TIME'.

To me this means that it's like the optional argument "mode" is somehow set to some value even if I didn't passe it to the function.

Can someone help please? :)

Comment: Are you sure f2py supports optional arguments?

Comment: So I checked the documentation and apparently f2py does not support optional arguments. The only way to do that is to initialize all the optional arguments in advance even if this won't solve my problem. Guess I have to change the fortran code in the end.